# pass parameters to screensaver

Tags: c#, screensaver

I was wondering if it is possible to run a screensaver (.scr) in preview mode from code. If I run the process normally it runs with the /s parameter, and I've attempted to pass my own /p parameter but windows seems to override it.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/p";
process.StartInfo.FileName = "MyScreensaver.scr";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
process.Start();
```

Doing it this way will result in MyScreensaver running with the "/s" parameter being passed in.